# NodeJS and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, web

I started to learn NodeJS and PostgreSQL and I have some problems with them. I made three tables which called authors, articles and branches. Everything is work good. For example when I wrote this: `select * from authors;` it shows me everything, I mean all authors. Then I decided to make server using NodeJS. And when it laucnhed I will write in browser this for example `http://localhost/articles` and it shows me authors and his articles. But I have one error and I don't know how to fix it. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
  const http = require('http');
  const path = require('path');
  const async = require('async');
  const socketio = require('socket.io');
  const express = require('express');


  var pg = require('pg')
  var format = require('pg-format')
  var PGUSER = 'person'
  var PGDATABASE = 'website'


  var config = {
      user: PGUSER, // name of the user account
      password: 'person',
      database: PGDATABASE, // name of the database
      max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  }

  var pool = new pg.Pool(config)
  var myClient;
  var data;

  var myQuery = `
    SELECT
        "authors"."name",
        "branches"."branch",
        "articles"."title",
        "articles"."text"
    FROM "articles"
    INNER JOIN "authors"
        USING ("id")
    INNER JOIN "branches"
        USING ("id")
    ORDER BY
        "authors"."name";
  `;

  // var pg = require('pg');
  // var conString = "postgres://person:person@localhost:5432/Website";

  // var client = new pg.Client(conString);
  // client.connect();

  pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  myClient = client
  var ageQuery = format(myQuery)
  myClient.query(ageQuery, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // return err;
      console.log(err);
      // return '<h1>err</h1>';
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0]);
    data = result.rows;
    // return res.end("<h1>yes</h1>");
  })
  });


  var router = express();
  var server = http.createServer(router);
  var io = socketio.listen(server);

  router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));

  var parser = require('./controllers/API_parser.js');

  server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, process.env.IP || "127.0.0.1", function(){
    var addr = server.address();
    console.log("Server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
  });


  router.get('/articles', function (req, res) {
      res.header('Content-type', 'text/html');

      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          result += "<h1>" + data[i]["name"] + "</h1>";
          result += "<h3>" + data[i]["branch"] + "</h3>";
          result += "<h2>" + data[i]["title"] + "</h2>";
          result += "<h4>" + data[i]["text"] + "</h4>";
          result += "<hr>";
      }

      // return res.end(parser.getDataFromDatabase());
      return res.end(result);
  });
```

Anf this is my error

```
Debugger listening on [::]:15454
Server listening at 0.0.0.0:8080
{ error: column "id" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table
at Connection.parseE (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
name: 'error',
length: 133,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42703',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'parse_clause.c',
line: '876',
routine: 'transformFromClauseItem' }
/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:57
console.log(result.rows[0]);
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
    at Query.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:57:21)
    at Query.handleError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:143:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
```

Comment: The TypeError is confusing, because it is not the real problem but only a problem with the error management. You should check if result is undefined before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that both of the tables being attached through the inner join have an id field?

This is the beginning of your stack trace

```
{ error: column "id" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table }
```

Comment: Thanks I found problem. I wrote id with lowercase not with upper